# Generate State Diagram Drag/Drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-applications

I would like to generate state diagram, for example as shown in the picture below.

I want to make this user friendly. If any user wants such diagram then he can just drag/drop the circles/arrows and connect them and put description (1,2,3..... a,b,c....) etc. It should be **web-based**.

I am not sure if there is opensource/free library to do this.

How to generate such diagram interactively ?

Any idea/suggestions are most welcome.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: I have edited and put question already. Thanks

Comment: There still is no concrede question. What is preventing you from building it? Obviously there arent any complete packages available, sometimes you'd have to put some effort into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware there is indeed no opensource/free library that does this.

Some online tools exist, but they mostly use a text-to-image convertion similar to what [yUML](http://yuml.me/) and [Websequencediagrams](http://www.websequencediagrams.com/) do.

You'd have to write the whole thing yourself, although something like [RaphealJS](http://raphaeljs.com/) or [jQuery SVG](http://keith-wood.name/svgRef.html) could do some of the heavy lifting for you in regards to rendering the graphs.

You might want to take a look at [Canviz](http://code.google.com/p/canviz/) and [wwwsqldesigner](http://code.google.com/p/wwwsqldesigner/) for inspiration.

Comment: Thanks Potherca. It seems that I have to start from scratch.

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for something along the same lines and found: [JointJS](http://www.jointjs.com/).  It looks like very promising for your purposes.  The examples should help get you started.

Answer (score 2):

[Finite State Machine Designer](http://madebyevan.com/fsm/) can be used to generate diagrams like that in the question with clicking/dragging/dropping.

It's also [open source](https://github.com/evanw/fsm), should you need to extend it.

Answer (score 1):

Have look at my web based [State Machine Diagram Editor](http://www.stateforge.com/StateMachineDiagram/StateMachineDiagram.html). A more convenient desktop version also exists.